# grep command to find previous word less than a number

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, grep

I need help with one grep command:

```
grep match-word tomcat-0.log.* | grep "TOMCAT BENCH" | grep -v Normal
```

The current output is simillar to:

```
tomcat-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 1420 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId>
```

I want to modify this to display only those lines which have elapsed value greater than a number like `3000`

The word `elapsed` is always present and the number is the word **before** `elapsed`.

Can you please modify the `grep` command to filter previous word and compare it with a number?

Comment: I think that `awk` is more suited for this kind of task....

Comment: Although the `awk` solutions are cleaner, I gave you a `grep` solution if you're interested. :)

Comment: i am unable to use awk since the logs are compressed and i am using zgrep actually to uncompress it first

Comment: Just use `zcat file | awk`. Anything else will be ridiculously complicated to modify when you need a different threshold.

Comment: @amitmah: You should have mentioned about the compressed file in question. Also as @Ed rightly suggested to you use `zcat` with `awk` as using multiple `grep` is not only inefficient it is not the right tool to do a numerical comparison.

Comment: @amitmah: May I politely ask why you removed the accepted checkmark from my answer? I answered it in the way you wanted, solving it with `grep` like you asked. Hence, you gave me the accepted checkmark. But then when your requirements changed, you accepted an answer that **didn't** meet your **original** requirements. Is it just me, or does that seem a little ... wrong?

Comment: This must be a mis-click, let me correct it back :(
Its hight time to get new Specs

Comment: @amitmah: Thanks for changing it back. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As asked for,** here is an all `grep` solution in all it's brute force glory:

```
... | grep -E "([1-9][0-9]{4,}|3[0-9]{2}[1-9]|3[0-9][1-9]0|[4-9][0-9]{3}) elapsed"
```

---

**Let's work through this solution:**

- `[1-9][0-9]{4,}` matches any number that is greater than 9999. Basically, it verifies that we have a numeric string with a digit in the `ten thousands place, 100 thousands place, ...` or higher that is greater than 0.
  <sub>For instance, `12000` would match, but `02000` would not match.</sub>
- `3[0-9]{2}[1-9]` matches all numbers `3001 - 3999` that do **NOT** end with a zero
- `3[0-9][1-9]0` matches numbers like `3010, 3120, 3990, etc.` that end in zero but are not less than or equal to 3000
- `[4-9][0-9]{3}` matches 4 digit numbers greater than `3999`

If one of the preceding patterns is matched, we make sure that it is immediately followed by the string " elapsed," in which case, we're finished.

---

**PS:** Remember, we have to match numbers *greater than* 3000.

**PPS:** Note that I assume that the string that comes before " elapsed" is always made up of numbers; I don't make sure that there is a space before we check for a number.

**PPPS:** This was done with `grep` because it is the tool for which a solution was asked. I am by no means suggesting that `grep` is a good way to do this ... **at all.**

**PPPPS:** Due to the format of the log that is being searched through, I don't expect to have to deal with negative numbers. Hence, I don't. :)

Comment: That regexp is much more complicated than it needs to be for what it's doing (it's equivalent to just `[3-9][0-9]{3}`) but more importantly it would fail to match 10000, 2000, etc. You can correct that to `([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]{3}` but it's still the wrong approach for doing a numeric comparison. Just use awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for your feedback! However, I think you're mistaken on a couple of points. First, it **is not** equivalent to `[3-9][0-9]{3}` because that matches `3000` and we're not supposed to! (*Note:* For some insane reason, I was matching 3000 separately even though I wasn't supposed to. However, the *partially* corrected solution above is no longer the same as `[3-9][0-9]{3}`.) Secondly, it's not supposed to match 2000. Thirdly, the OP asked for a `grep` solution, later stating that he couldn't use `awk`. Hence, I will stand by my answer after updating it to allow larger numbers. :D

Comment: @EdMorton: There. I gave some reader notes and it now handles numbers greater than 9999. JSYK.

Comment: The regexp you had absolutely WAS equivalent to what I posted in my comment and it DID match 3000 as you said yourself in your comment, and of course I meant 20000, not 2000 in my comment. I understand why you posted a grep solution, the OP is simply wrong in stating he can't use awk and IMHO could benefit from a point in the right direction rather than just giving him what he asked for.

Comment: @EdMorton: In truth, I agree with you. As you can see, I did clarify the fact that `grep` is not a good way to do this, personally preferring the `awk` solutions since they are cleaner, more elegant, and more flexible. (Truthfully, I've +!d a couple of the `awk` solutions since they're the preferable way to do it.) Even though I got a little militant about my post (I'll admit - I was nitpicking so I had more points), I likely would've said something about `zcat`, had I known that it existed. Anyways, thanks for your comments - they brought 2 errors *(now fixed)* to my attention. Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Using gnu awk this can be done in a single command:

```
awk '/TOMCAT BENCH/ && !/Normal/ && match($0, / ([0-9]+) elapsed /, a) && a[1] > 3000' tomcat-0.log.*
```

Comment: Using POSIX awk one can do: **`awk '/TOMCAT BENCH/ && !/Normal/ && match($0, / ([0-9]+) elapsed /) && (p=substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)) != "" && sub(/ .*/, "", p) && p > 3000' log.txt`**

Comment: POSIXly I had `awk '/TOMCAT BENCH/ && !/Normal/{s=$0; $0=substr($0,1,index($0,"elapsed"))} $(NF-1) > 3000{print s}'` but its the same idea so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, all you need is:

```
zcat file |
awk -F ' *elapsed.*' '/TOMCAT BENCH/ && !/Normal/{n=$1;sub(/.* /,"",n)} n>3000'
```

e.g. with your posted one line of sample input:

```
$ cat file |
awk -F ' *elapsed.*' '/TOMCAT BENCH/ && !/Normal/{n=$1;sub(/.* /,"",n)} n>1400'
tomcat-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 1420 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId>
```

Comment: Thanks this was easier to change the time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `awk` command as follows:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i == "elapsed") { if ($(i-1) >3000 ) print; } }}' file
```

Assuming your sample input file is

```
$ cat file
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 1420 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 5420 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 420  elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 3100 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text  0 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 6596 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId>
```

Running the `awk` command produces

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i == "elapsed") { if ($(i-1) >3000 ) print; } }}' file
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 5420 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 3100 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId> 
t-0.log:TOMCAT BENCH: match_word random-text 6596 elapsed Thu 2016-09-22 06:31:04:928 PDT <SessionID: id> <RequestID: reqId>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
| awk 'match($0, / ([0-9]+) elapsed /, a) && a[1] > 3000'
```

in the end of your command:

```
grep match_word tomcat-0.log.* | grep "TOMCAT BENCH" | grep -v Normal | awk 'match($0, / ([0-9]+) elapsed /, a) && a[1] > 3000'
```

Comment: No actually as per my question there is a random text in between so i can not predict the column number

Comment: Just to fix my answer, this command will wok in any situation. But of course the best solution was given by anubhava.

Comment: Your solution is gawk-specific due to the 3rd arg to match() so maybe it's failing for the OP because he's not using gawk.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

```
... | grep elapsed | numgrep /3000../
```